# insert all of an associative array in database in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel-4

i want to insert all of an associative array in my table which each index of array will be in a single row of table.

here is my code:

```
public function confirmQuestion($id_array)
    {
        $quiz_id = explode(',',$id_array);

        $lesson = array();
        foreach($quiz_id as $q)
        {
            $lesson[] = DB::select("select lesson_id from quiz where '$q' = id");
        }

        $lesson_id = array();
        foreach($lesson as $key=>$value)
        {
            $lesson_id[] = $value[0]->lesson_id;
        }

        $data = array_combine($quiz_id , $lesson_id);

    }
```

i want the $data to be inserted in my table. every index of array in a row of table.

here is my associative array:

```
array(3) { [10]=> int(15) [11]=> int(15) [12]=> int(15) }
```

Comment: you need to change the array into string

Answer (score 0):

at first, can you tell us more about the context ?
Do you use a framework ?
Can you be more precise about the data you have in your array and what your table must look like ?

EDIT: since you're using laravel 4 and according to the page http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries :

Inserting Records Into A Table

```
DB::table('users')->insert(
    array('email' => 'john@example.com', 'votes' => 0)
);
```

Inserting Multiple Records Into A Table

```
DB::table('users')->insert(array(
    array('email' => 'taylor@example.com', 'votes' => 0),
    array('email' => 'dayle@example.com', 'votes' => 0),
));
```

Comment: yeah can't comment the question, don't understand why you need reputation to do so... but the edit does provide an answer ;)